All of my group members' names are shown in bold and black font. How can I tell which have blocked me as an Admin?
I've read countless posts that state that an Admin can check their members list, and any of the members that have blocked Admins will show up as bold and black font.
Not so...every member of my group shows up in bold and black font.  There's no deviation.  Short of going through each and every member individually ( I have 70K + members as of today), how can I know who has blocked me?

If you are going to reference "countless posts" you should provide links to a few examples.  Especially given you are not referencing Facebook documentation.

Group members that have blocked you will show as unavailable.
Source:
Using Facebook > Groups > What it means that a Facebook group member is unavailable
What it means that a Facebook group member is unavailable
As a group admin, you may see some group members listed in the Unavailable section of the member list. These accounts might be unavailable for several reasons. They may have blocked you, been blocked by you, been deactivated, or are pending account verification.
Admins can see all actions that unavailable members take within the group like posts and comments. Admins can also remove or ban unavailable members.
To view a list of unavailable names in a group you manage:

Go to facebook.com/groups and select your group.
Click Members at the top. If you don't see Members, click More, then click Members.
Scroll down to the Unavailable section. If you don't see Unavailable, that means none of your group members are unavailable.

